# Undeploy or deactivate an AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

Is there a way to undeploy or deactivate an AWS Lambda or must I either implement it myself or delete and later redeploy it to achieve the desired state? What I would like is similar to just "undeploying it" so that it can be deployed again later.

Comment: I'm unsure I get you, the lambda being deployed doesn't mean it will run unless scheduled or triggered by an event, so if you just want it to sit there you should just remove the event firing it

Comment: @Tensibai It is scheduled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can change the trigger working process and rewrite and re schedule the process. Which the way you want.
it will work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: and how to do so ?

Comment: you should be able to find it under Lambda->function->(your lambda name) now under Designer tab you should see triggers. Click on one and under it you should see a disabled sliding button

Comment: Is there a way to do this enable/disable of trigger by any API/program?

Comment: ideally one could make it "sleep/inactive" with one click in the console. I didn't finy any such option whatsoever.